# Best method to handle asynchronous Firebase calls in Nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firebase, nightwatch.js

I have a Nightwatch test that creates a new user, then looks up the user's data in Firebase. The problem is, the tests happen asynchronously because the Firebase code is using promises, so I have delay the Firebase query with setTimeOut to give the test time to create the user before I look it up. The Javscript code looks like this:

```
driver.page.landing().navigate()
    .waitForPageLoad()
    .setValue('@emailField', user.email)
    .click('@submitButton')
  driver.pause(5000)

setTimeout(()=> {
    firebase.getLeadsInfoByEmail(user.email).then(result => {
      firebase.exitFirebase()

    driver.page.register()
        .assert.equal(result.email, user.email)
    })
  }, 6000)
}
};
```

My question is: is there another way to code it so the Firebase query happens *after* certain code has already run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: since Node.js executes statements asynchronously, you need to use the Nightwatch Perform function to run as part of a queue. So the code would look like:

```
 driver.page.landing().navigate()
    .waitForPageLoad()
    .setValue('@emailField', user.email)
    .click('@submitButton')
    .api.perform(function() {
      firebase.getLeadsInfoByEmail(user.email).then(result => {
        firebase.exitFirebase()
        driver.page.register()
          .assert.equal(result.email, user.email)
    })
  }
};
```